# How to get the width and heigh of an imageview

Tags: android

I have this XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInner"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@layout/gallery_image_background"
/>
```

Then this code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutInner = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutInner);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(thisActivityContext);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.example);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
linearLayoutInner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
linearLayoutInner.addView(imageView);
```

I then call an own function that is meant to scale the bitmap image until one of the sides reach the edge (i.e. so if the original bitmat is twice as wide as tall, it will keep the proportion inside the imageview, something that is apparently not supported by any scaletype setting):

```
SharedCode.sharedUtilScaleImage(imageView);
```

And here comes the problem. That function needs to know the size of the view containing the bitmap drawable. if imageView behaves correctly, it should use **MATCH_PARENT** and hence give the width/height of the **linearLayoutInner**. However, the following code returns zero:

```
int heightParent = max(imageView.getLayoutParams().height, imageView.getHeight());      
int widthParent = max(imageView.getLayoutParams().width, imageView.getWidth());
```

How do I solve this? And why am I returned 0 instead of the correct height/width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably calling the code too early, before the View's onMeasure() has been called. Until that happens, its size is unknown.

```
final ImageView iv....
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //Measure
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: (Upvoted) At what point is this onMeasure called? (If it is only called once, I guess I could create some code that would wait.) I need to be able to pass in ImageView references on demand. The heigh/width of the imageview/linearlayout should **never change** after the initial creation. (The bimaps change of course corresponding to click events on another control.)

Comment: @Tom onMeasure() is called once before the View is drawn the first time, and it is called again whenever the size changes.

Comment: I am having my `ImageView` change to 0 after a configuration change. I tried this code, but it is still not working for some reason. Anyone else have a configuration change issue that might have used this successfully? Trying to resize a bitmap, but can't with an `ImageView=0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView )findViewById(R.id.image_test);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            imageView .getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            imageView.getHeight(); // This will return actual height.
            imageView.getWidth(); // This will return actual width.
        }
    });
```

Comment: (Upvoted)  Thanks for the answer. I still find it odd that the height/width is not even accessible on **onWindowFocusChanged()**, but I will try this method instead, and try combine it with my existing code somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you might be calling from `onCreate()`. u need to wait for activity window to attached and then call `getWidth()` and`getHeight()` on `imageView`.You can try calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` from `onWindowFocusChanged()` method of your activity.

**Edit**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    int width=imageView.getWidth();
    int height=imageView.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: (Upvoted) It made no difference calling from onWindowFocusChanged :(